# Declaring classes inside a python module

Tags: python

I have a python module that I've made that contains regular function defintions as well as classes.  For some reason when I call the constructor and pass a value, it's not updating the class variable.

My module is called VODControl (VODControl.py).  The class I have declared inside the module is called DRMPath.  The DRMPath class has two instance vairables: logfile and results.  logfile is a string and results is a dictionary.

My constructor looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, file):
    self.logilfe = file
    self.results['GbE1'] = ""
    self.results['GbE2'] = ""
    self.results['NetCrypt'] = ""
    self.results['QAM'] = ""
```

when I import it from my other python script I do:

```
import VODControl
```

The call i use is the following:

```
d = VODControl.DRMPath('/tmp/adk.log')
```

However, when I print the value of the logfile instance variable, it isn't updated with what I passed to the constructor:

```
print d.logfile
```

After printing, it's still an empty string.  What gives?

Comment: I would recommend renaming the `file` parameter to `fname` or something, as you're currently shadowing the [builtin file type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)

Comment: +1 for posting the *exact* code, which includes the logilfe typo. Too many posters insert a snippet that reflects what they *meant* to write, but which omits the key typo or other boo-boo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.logilfe = file` is not the same as `self.logfile = file` In addition, it is likely returning `None`, not an empty string.

Comment: Well don't I feel like a huge jackass.  Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes.  Thank the gods that I have StackOverflow instead of my coworkers to make a fool of myself in front of.  Thanks fellas, the mispelling was it... duh